# Indicator method for isolated chairs

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am working on the following problem for an applied probability qualifying exam.

Fix positive integers $m\leq n$ with $n>4$. Suppose $m$ people sit at a circular table with n seats, with all ${n \choose m}$ seatings equally likely. A seat is called isolated if it is occupied and both adjacent seats are vacant. Find the mean and variance of the number of isolated seats.

Letting $X$ be the number of isolated seats, I have written $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{1}_{A_{i}}$, where $A_{i}=\{$$i^{th}$ seat is isolated$\}$ for i=2,...,n-1, and $A_{1}$ and $A_{n}$ defined appropriately given the circular arrangement. This yields $\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}(A_{i})$. Now I know that $A_{i}$ occurs only when chairs $i\pm1$ are vacant and chair $i$ is occupied.

I mistakenly initially computed that the probability is $p(1-p)^2$ where $p$ is the probability of a single chair being occupied (which turned out to be $m/n$). However, since these events are not independent, I am unsure how to compute the actual probability.

Comment: Once a chair is occupied, it's isolated if the other $m-1$ people sit in the $n-3$ non-adjacent chairs.

Comment: Hint:  The only way you can get an isolated seat is if $n \geq m+2$.  For the case $n = m+2$ there is only $1$ way to get an isolated seat.  (I'm assuming you accept rotational symmetry around the table.)  If $n = m+3$, there is just one way to get $2$ isolated seats.  The number of ways to get $1$ isolated seat is the number of ways you can place the third empty chair at least two seats away from the two "adjacent" chairs.  Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

$A_i$ = 1 if $i$ th seat is isolated.

P($A_i$ = 1) = $\frac {n-3 \choose m-1}{{n \choose m}}$

Therefore E[ X ] = $ n \times \frac {n-3 \choose m-1}{{n \choose m}}$